# Is Appium able run a test that touches 2 different apps, one iOS and the other Android at the same time?

Tags: java, android, ios, junit, appium

**Context**: I am working with a project that involves an android-controlled hardware and an iOS app that talks to that android device via websocket. We are in a good shape in terms of lower level (API, unit, contract) testing, but there's nothing to help us with the UI part of it.

*UI automation, especially end-to-end is not my favorite way of testing because it is flaky and slow, and I believe it's purpose is only to guarantee that the main user flows are executable rather than every single piece of functionality.*

So I developed a suite that includes both the android and the iOS code and page objects, but right now the only thing I can do is run each one of them individually:

- Start the appium server and appium driver for android, run the android app suite
- Start the appium server and appium driver for ios, run the ios app suite

But that is not quite exactly what I want - since this is going to be the only test case, I want it to be full end-to-end; starts appium server, starts android server, also start appium drivers for both, run test that places an action on ios and verifies that android is executing it.

*I don't want to have someone manually running this thing and looking at both devices. If this doesn't work, android and ios suites are going to run separately, relying on mocked counterparts.*

So I am throwing it here to the community because none of the test engineering groups I posted to were able to come up with an answer.

I need to know if anyone has ever done or seen this to shed me a light, or if anyone knows how to do it.

[Can Steve Jobs and Andy Rubin talk?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFB8U.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it was as simple as it looked like.

What I did was to implement an abstract class that builds drivers for both android and ios with their capabilities and specific appium port, instantiating their respective page objects as well. All the test classes extend this abstract class.

Then I divided the suite in 3 pieces:
One for the Android only, which only accesses the page objects for android; 
One for ios, which also accesses only the page objects for ios;
And a third test that spins up both ios and android and controls them both.

To avoid always starting two appium servers and also avoid always downloading the latest app versions for both android and ios I created gradle tasks for each platform, so the CI jobs can call only the task that prepares for the platform it has to test at a given moment.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into starting 2 appium instances via command line on different ports and then connecting each suite to a given appium instance. Then at this point you just need to properly thread each suite so that you can properly test your code. To do that you will need to add dependencies (can be easily done using TestNG).

Steps:

1) Create a thread for IOS and Android Suites

2) Run each suite on a different appium session (aka different ports)

```
 - You will need to know how to run from command line for this
```

3) Setup your tests to depend on one another (I recommend using TestNG as the framework)

4) Use threading logic to properly wait for tests to finish before starting. Yields and Timeouts will be very useful, as well as TestNG dependencies, it will save your life given what you are doing.

NOTE: Appium has a timeout functionality where if a session does not get a command in 60 seconds by default the session is destroyed. AKA make sure you increase or find a way to turn off that timeout.

Additionally as a recommendation I would advise the use of TestNG over JUnit. JUnit is a Unit testing framework, meaning you are testing specific functional units. This however is not ideal for app automation as many areas of an app depend on prior functionality. For example if you have a login screen where the login functionality is currently broken you don't want to run all of the tests the need the user to be logged in to pass. This would cause not only a lot of fright when a large portion of your tests fail, it will also make it harder to track down why it failed. Instead if you have all of these tests depend on the login feature passing then if the login fails there is a single error which can then be fixed, and all the tests that depend on the login feature don't run when you know they are going to pass.

Hope this process helps, sorry I obviously can't send out code in this as it would take hours for me to type/figure out.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Jayson. I haven't thought about using testNG, especially because, as I wrote in my question, this is going to be single test case that runs thru the whole user flow, which includes both android and ios. Individual areas are covered by other types of tests, that is why jUnit is not going to be a problem in this suite right now. 
In regards to command line on item #2 I am pretty comfortable with it, won't be a problem, in fact I've tried up 2 appium servers on diff ports but something failed, maybe that's where TestNG could help.

Thanks for sharing your thoughts!